# Is it possible to also display the parameters in Nunit Allure Steps, like it is in Java?

Tags: c#, automated-tests, nunit, allure

Is it possible to add steps to Allure reports when writing Nunit tests, that will also include and display the parameters the method is using (like in Intellij)?
At the moment I am using NUnit.Allure.Steps, but this only displays the name of the stem in the report.
example:

```
[AllureStep("This is my step")]
public static void stepExample(string param)
{
}
```

When I write the same in Java in IntelliJ using import io.qameta.allure.Step, i also see the 'param' displayed under the step in the report.

```
@Step("Test Flow: Login")
public static void login(String user, String password)
{
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I tried something and it worked, but it doesnt look quit the same as when I run from Intellij.

```
[AllureStep("This is my step. {0}, {1}")]
public static void login(string param1, string param2)
{
}
```